# C# Find Data From A List

Tags: c#, sql, list, singleton

I have a list of Teachers and I would like to be able to display all data from the list of a specific teacher. I would like to search by name. However, either my list stays empty or I could not get the data from it. I do not know where the problem is.

Here is how i load the data from my sql server database to my list:

```
    public void connectDbRead(List<Teacher> Teachers)
    {
        var teacherData = TeacherData.GetInstance();
        //Get all students in the singleton
        var teachers = teacherData.Teachers;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {               
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=true";
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TEACHERS", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("0", 1));

            teachers.Clear();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {                   
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    teachers.Add(new Teacher
                    {
                        Name = (string)reader["NAME"],
                        FamilyName = (string)reader["FAMILY_NAME"],
                        Age = (int)reader["AGE"]                           
                    });

                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} | {1}| {2}",
                        reader[1], reader[2], reader[3]));
                }
            }              
        }
    }
```

Here is how I search the data from the list:

```
    public void searchTeacher(List<Teacher> Teachers)
    {       
        string teacherName = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Who do you want to find. Write his name: ");
        teacherName = Console.ReadLine();

        List<Teacher> teachers = Teachers.FindAll(x => x.Name == teacherName);

        Console.WriteLine("List Of ELements!");
        foreach (Teacher t in teachers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }
   }
```

I call it in the main function like that, but in switch cases:

```
        var teacherData = TeacherData.GetInstance();
        var teachers = teacherData.Teachers;                
        teacherData.searchTeacher(teachers);                     
        teacherData.connectDbRead(teachers);
```

Comment: Why don't you use Linq to SQL? check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/getting-started

Comment: Are you trying to do a partial comparison, or an exact match? Is the casing the same? Perhaps you should do `teachers = Teachers.Where(t => string.Equals(t.Name, teacherName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));` Or, if you're doing a parial search, then `.Where(t => t.IndexOf(teacherName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)`

Comment: I want to do a search in the list, but stays empty. I am able only to get the whole list and not to delete or search data. I tried to apply your code, but it still does not work: List<Teacher> newList = Teachers.FindAll(x => x.Name.Equals(teacherName)); Also, I am calling it like that: foreach (Teacher t in newList)
            {              
              Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());               
            }

Answer (score 0):

One line solution(don't even need to use LINQ) :

```
foreach(teachers t in Teacher)

  if (t.Name == "TeacherName or any searcj query")

    MessageBox.Show(t.name & t.age & .......)
```

Or if you still want to use LINQ :

```
 forech(Teachers t in Teacher)

  var result = Teachers.Where(Teacher => t.Name == "Name Here")

 /// use the result as u want )
```

Comment: The thing is that line does not work I think. It does not recognise any data in teachers: List<Teacher> teachers = Teachers.FindAll(x => x.Name == teacherName);

Comment: `List<Teacher> Teachers` , why would u need to use this as a parameter ? it is nonsense , rather create a new instance of it , that's all :)

Comment: Yes, I would rather use LINQ, but whatever I do, the list is still empty: var result = Teachers.Where(Teacher => Teacher.name == teacherName);

            Console.WriteLine("List Of ELements!");
            foreach (Teacher t in result)
            {    
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            }

Comment: If I do it like that, I get all the data from the list: foreach (Teacher t in Teachers)
            {    
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            }   But, I need to search by name.

Comment: look closely , i typed `foreach(teachers t in Teacher)``if (t.name=="name here")` `console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 0):

I changed things around a bit; deleted some things that I didn't understand but I tested it this way and it worked.

```
class Program
    {
        static List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            connectDbRead();
            searchTeacher();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void connectDbRead()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=true"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TEACHERS", conn);

                teachers.Clear();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        teachers.Add(new Teacher
                        {
                            Name = (string)reader["NAME"],
                            FamilyName = (string)reader["FAMILY_NAME"],
                            Age = (int)reader["AGE"]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void searchTeacher()
        {
            string teacherName = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Who do you want to find. Write his name: ");
            teacherName = Console.ReadLine();

            var foundTeachers = teachers.FindAll(x => x.Name == teacherName);

            Console.WriteLine("List Of ELements!");
            foreach (Teacher t in foundTeachers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}", t.Name, t.FamilyName, t.Age));
            }
        }
    }
    public class Teacher
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FamilyName  { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It still does not work on my end. I cannot get in the foreach cycle unless I do it like that: foreach (Teacher t in Teachers) {Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());}, but that way I go through all of the data and cannot find one specific teacher.

Comment: You have declared teachers at the form level, yes? And change `List<Teacher> teachers = Teachers.FindAll(x => x.Name == teacherName);` to `var foundTeachers = teachers.FindAll(x => x.Name == teacherName);` It did work with a sample database I use.